# Separating two interleaved arrays into continuous sequences

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not sure how to best explain my question in words, so I will provide a code example below. But to at least give it a try. I am solving an eigenvalue problem as a function of some external parameter, which results in two eigenvalues. Those two eigenvalues cross, as the function of the external parameter. Eigenvalue sorting then leads to the wrong classification of which eigenvalue belongs to what 'branch' of the problem. I'd like to disentangle that.

Okay, as for the example. We start from the desired result and then mess it up according to what happens in the diagonalization routine.

```
xs = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, 0.001)
fun_a = np.cos(xs) + 0.5*np.sin(xs)
fun_b = np.cos(xs) - 0.5*xs*np.sin(xs) + 0.2

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, fun_a)
plt.plot(xs, fun_b)
```

This results in two smooth branches that cross each other:

[image]

Now, what happens is that instead the eigenvalues are sorted, which I can mimmic as follows:

```
fun_c = np.zeros_like(fun_a)
fun_c[fun_a>fun_b] = fun_a[fun_a>fun_b]
fun_c[fun_a<=fun_b] = fun_b[fun_a<=fun_b]

fun_d = np.zeros_like(fun_a)
fun_d[fun_a>fun_b] = fun_b[fun_a>fun_b]
fun_d[fun_a<=fun_b] = fun_a[fun_a<=fun_b]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs, fun_c)
plt.plot(xs, fun_d)
```

The result is these two branches, which are no longer smooth, continuous branches

[image]

What my question boils down to is how we can go from the second case (fun_c, fun_d) to the first case (fun_a, fun_b). I suppose one could use the information in the derivative, to some extent. Using `np.diff()` reveals a sharp discontinuity at the point where things go wrong. But I don't immediately see how to nicely use that.

edit: I'm starting to think the best assignment would be such that each subsequent point is chosen to minimize the change in the slope. But I'm not yet sure how to do that..

Comment: How about: if both functions have a discontinuity at the same point, you switch the latter parts of the arrays. Then repeat until there are no more discontinuities.

Comment: @Johannes if, by chance, the two functions cross on a single point but do not change order, that wouldn't work. Maybe unlikely, but not impossible (especially with trigonometric functions).

Comment: That is true (about the crossing without changing order), but that sounds like a hard case to account for in general. Maybe to start with it'd be alright to ignore that..

Comment: @user129412 I agree, I had initially the same idea as Johannes before I realized this flaw. Btw, it's not that hard to get such a case, for instance `sin(x)` and `sin(x+π)+2` ;)

Comment: I don't think there's a problem in that case! Given those functions and the above code it'll switch the two branches, but they remain continuous. That's all that I require

Comment: @mozway I think a solution would be (after starting with a random assignment for the first index) to check for each next index which of the two possible assignments leads to the smallest change. That should cover also the case you mentioned, I think

Comment: 1. Sum the two branches. 2. FFT. 3. synthesize each frequency separately.

Comment: @yannziselman that might work, but how to take into account the shift between functions?

Comment: @rikyeah why would you need to? how do you define that "shift"? the two waves gain phase at different rates. there is no constant phase difference you can compute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many adjustments to be made to improve performance, but here's my guess, based on second derivative thresholding:

```
# first derivative
deriv = np.diff(fun_c)
# second derivative
deriv2 = np.diff(deriv)
# adjust threshold to detect discontinuities
switch_points = deriv2 > 0.0002
# indices of points of intersection
touch_index = np.where(switch_points == True)[0]
# adjustment to prevent false positives
# (sometimes contigous samples like 127,128 are both detected)
duplicate_index = np.where(np.diff(touch_index) == 1)[0]
touch_index = np.delete(touch_index, duplicate_index)
# begin and ending points of sections to swap
begins = touch_index[::2]
ends = touch_index[1::2]

from itertools import zip_longest

# swap values in selected sections
tmp = fun_c.copy() # need a tmp array to swap
for begin, end in zip_longest(begins, ends, fillvalue=len(fun_c)):
    tmp[begin:end] = fun_d[begin:end]

# complete swapping, correcting fun_d
# on the indices we changed before
swapped = tmp != fun_c
fun_d[swapped] = fun_c[swapped]
fun_c = tmp

plt.plot(xs, fun_c)
plt.plot(xs, fun_d)
```

[image: separated sin functions]

I found it quite dependant on the sampling_rate (might fail if it is too low).

Edit:
If it wasn't for the

```
touch_index = np.delete(touch_index, duplicate_index)
```

you could entirely skip all this:

```
begins = touch_index[::2]
ends = touch_index[1::2]
from itertools import zip_longest
# swap values in selected sections
tmp = fun_c.copy() # need a tmp array to swap
for begin, end in zip_longest(begins, ends, fillvalue=len(fun_c)):
    tmp[begin:end] = fun_d[begin:end]
```

with just

```
np.logical_xor.accumulate(touch_index) | touch_index
```